# How to get out a variable from a function?

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

So, I'm trying to get a variable out of a function. I have a Garry's Mod script which contains this statement:

```
http.Fetch("http://google.fr",  function(body)
    return body
end)
```

My question is: how to retrieve my body variable out of this? I think that there's no such thing as "global" keyword (like in PHP for example) or references in Lua.
Thanks!

Comment: If you have a function that returns a variable, then `local result = foo()`...

Comment: The callback you pass won't be called until after the page is fetched, which will be well after the function calling `http.Fetch` returns.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I don't fully understand and I can't get it to work this way.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo You're right, so my code **should** be inbetween the callback function so I can't use the body value if the page hasn't loaded. But is there still a way to retrieve the variable out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way for you to handle this would be to write a function that physically loads the `body` result to whatever interface you are using, or to add code inside the Fetch call to load it yourself. Something like this:

```
-- just an example of some function that knew how to load a body result 
-- in your context
function setBody(body) 
    someapi.Display(body)
end

http.Fetch('http://someurl.com', 
    function(body) 
        -- you have access to outer functions from this scope. if you have
        -- some function or method for loading the response, invoke it here
        setBody(body)
        -- or just someapi.Display(body)
    end
)
```

I think you are confused because you seem to be in more of a functional design mindset, and you're now mixing in event driven design. in the event driven design, you are basically calling functions with params and giving them a function callback that has some code that you want to eventually run once the function you invoked completes.

Also, there *is* a global keyword of sorts in Lua - you have the global table `_G`. You could potentially set `_G.body = body`, but I would avoid that and pass around callback functions that know how to load things once they are invoked.

Comment: Thanks, I was, indeed, confused. I don't use callback functions in my usual PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't simply return the value from a function, you can us an [upvalue](http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html) to update, which will be available after the function is executed:

```
local bodycopy
http.Fetch("http://google.fr",  function(body)
    bodycopy = body
end)
-- assuming http.Fetch block here until the content of the URL is retrieved...
print(bodycopy)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think that there's no such thing as "global" keyword (like in PHP for example) or references in Lua.

There's [closures](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html), which will let you access variables defined as `local` in a subfunction.

For example:

```
function makeCounter()
    local i = 0
    local function counterfunc()
        i = i + 1
        return i
    end
    return coutnerfunc
end

local counter1 = makeCounter()
print(counter1()) -- 1
print(counter1()) -- 2
print(counter1()) -- 3

local counter2 = makeCounter()
print(counter2()) -- 1
print(counter2()) -- 2

print(counter1()) -- 4
```

This means you can store objects for use in your callback function.

```
function ENT:GetPage()
    -- The implicitly-defined self variable...
    http.Fetch("www.example.com", function(body)
        -- ...is still available here.
        self.results = body
    end)
end
```

Note that `http.Fetch` is an asynchronous function; it calls the callback later when the page is actually fetched. This won't work:

```
function ENT:GetPage()
    local results
    http.Fetch("www.example.com", function(body)
        results = body
    end)
    return results -- The closure hasn't been called yet, so this is still nil.
end
```